# Integer to NSInteger And Save To Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I have a integer named marbles, and am trying to save it into an array using the following code:

```
[records setValue:marbles forKey:@"marbles"];
```

With this code, I get the warning:

warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'

So, How do I set the value for an NSInteger.

Next Question, How do re-upload the array into core data? I fetch the array, make changes, and how do I apply those changes back to Core Data?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Initialize an NSNumber (which is what CoreData is expecting) with your integer:

```
NSNumber *marbleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:marbles];
[records setObject:marbleNumber forKey@"marbles"];
```

Or:

```
[records setMarbles:[NSNumber numberWithInt:marbles]];
```

To persist your changes, you save your context:

```
NSError *error;
[myManagedObjectContext save:&error];

//handle your error
```

Answer (score 6):

NSArrays will only take objects, so the first step is to turn your NSInteger into a NSNumber using this method:

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value
```

so:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:marbles];
```

and then you can do:

```
[records setValue:myNumber forKey:@"marbles"];
```

Basically once you fetch the data, you get a managedObjectContext, think of it as a drawing board, and any changes (including adding or deleting new objects), you make to this objects may be saved again to CoreData using something like this:

```
NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);  // Fail
        }
```

Where context is the context you would get with your NSFetchedResultsController. Which you can get like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
```

I would recommend taking a look at the [Core Data programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)primitiveValueForKey:(NSString *)key;    
- (void)setPrimitiveValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key;
```

use NSNumber in place of (id)value